# Dotspatial inconsistent type conversions

Tags: c#, types, dotspatial

I am finding a strange occurrence when using the Dotspatial (1.9) libraries.

When I load a shapefile into ArcMap and look at the data type of a shapefile, I am seeing it as a double type:

[image]

When I load this same shapefile using the Dotspatial library:

```
OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
od.Filter = "Shapefiles (*.shp)|*.shp";
if (od.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
     IFeatureSet feature_ = FeatureSet.Open(od.FileName);
     MessageBox.Show(feature_.DataTable.Columns["Northing"].DataType.ToString());    
 }
```

The result is only a Single:

[image]

This is causing some major truncating of the data when using the Save() in the dotspatial library. Does anyone know why this is happening or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this problem was recently fixed in version 2.0.